# RMI - create thread on server to serve client

Tags: java, multithreading, rmi

I'm developing a application using rmi which allow client to login, perform some task and logout. I know that each client is considered as one thread when it call a method on server, however, all clients' threads call to the same object created on server. So now, I want to for each client login successfully, a new thread is created (and a new object, which is used by only one client, is binded, too), a thread terminates when client logout. Hence, each client has its own server's object to work with.

Thank you very much.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

> I know that each client is considered
>   as one thread when it call a method on
>   server

That's not correct. The relationship between clients and server threads is undefined in RMI.

In any case you don't need a thread per client. You need a *remote object* per client. This is a job for the Session pattern:

```
public interface Login extends Remote
{
  Session login(String credentials) throws RemoteException;
}

public interface Session extends Remote
{
  // Your API here
}
```

Have your Login implementation object return a new Session implementation object for every client.